# Deletar Usuario Identity

Tags: .net, asp

Sou novo com o *Identity*, estou com dificuldade para implementar o método de Deletar usuários já cadastrados. Já fiz a Action, gerei a View, mas não tenho conhecimento de qual métodos do *Identity* utilizar para fazer tal operação. Pesquisei no Google, mas devo está colocando errado, porque não encontrei nada até agora.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id, IdentityUser user)
{
    try
    {
        _userManager.RemoveFromRoles(id = UserId);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

Só fiz a Action até agora:

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid ID)
{
    return View(UserManager.FindById(ID));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id, IdentityUser user)
{
    try
    {
        _userManager.RemoveFromRoles(id = UserId);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Se puder colocar um trecho de código, a pergunta ficou um pouco confusa. Identity nada mais é que o incremento de um valor, então não sei o que isso influencia em deletar valorer, a não ser que esse valor seja chave em outra ou mais tabelas.

Comment: Desculpa @Rafa_Developer, ficou meio vago mesmo. Estou usando o Identity para autentificação de usuários, aquele que trabalha com Claims , Roles... Estou fazendo o CRUD de deletar o usuário, mas não sei quais os métodos do Identity utilizar pra fazer isso.

Fiz só uma Action até agora. Irei mostrar logo abaixo

Comment: @CesarAlvesPereira não adicione respostas, clique no botão **editar** no canto inferior esquerdo quando quiser adicionar algo novo a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta baseada nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980216/6200920) do SO:

No código abaixo é deletado todos os *logins* do usuário, o usuários das *roles* e, por fim, o usuário

```
// POST: /Users/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (id == null)
    {
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    var logins = user.Logins;
    var rolesForUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(id);

    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
      foreach (var login in logins.ToList())
      {
        await _userManager.RemoveLoginAsync(login.UserId, new UserLoginInfo(login.LoginProvider, login.ProviderKey));
      }

      if (rolesForUser.Count() > 0)
      {
        foreach (var item in rolesForUser.ToList())
        {
          // item should be the name of the role
          var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id, item);
        }
      }

      await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
      transaction.commit();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  else
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Provavelmente você terá que fazer um ajuste ou outro no código, mas o caminho é esse.